# I am getting the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PureComponent' of undefined in my console of the react app.What is it expecting?

Tags: css, reactjs, image, crop

I have a react app, that uses react-image-crop package for creating crops of images available in the application.I am using this CSS import for crop CSS properties - import 'react-image-crop/dist/ReactCrop.css'. The below mentioned error is shown in console. What change is it expecting? Uncaught TypeError: **Cannot read property 'PureComponent' of undefined,at Module. (VM253 ReactCrop.min.js:1),at r (VM253 ReactCrop.min.js:1)**

Comment: You need to provide context or some minimum code so that we can help!

Comment: It was causing because of the css file import used for react-image-crop.